# Difficulty in setting dynamic setting CustomView to center of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have CustomView which is just an arc shape with some lines.

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
private Paint paint = new Paint();

public CustomDrawableView(Context context, int startA, int endA) {
    super(context);
     int x = 0;
     int y = 0;
     int width = 400;
     int height = 400;

     paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

     mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(startA, endA));
     mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
     mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
     }

     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     mDrawable.draw(canvas);
     canvas.drawLine(0,0,400,0,paint);
     canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, 400, paint);
     canvas.drawLine(400,0, 400,400, paint);
    }
}
```

Afterward I call out my linear layout from the xml file through its id add a framelayout to it. After that, I add CustomDrawableView and try to center it by using gravity. I went through many other questions and tried those solutions, but it just doesn't work for me. If it's worth noting, I notice when I use a regular view like a textview with no custom view in my layout, it centers perfectly.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private RelativeLayout ll;
private CustomDrawableView testView;  
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // load the layout
    LinearLayout linLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
    linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);




    /******** Experimental Code **********/
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    linLayout.addView(rl);

    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    CustomDrawableView arc = new CustomDrawableView(this,0,30);
    CustomDrawableView arcTwo = new CustomDrawableView(this, 50, 30);
    rl.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    rl.addView(arc, lp);
    rl.addView(arcTwo, lp);

    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY); } 

   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I use the frame layout in so i can lay views over each other.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to set `rl`'s layout_width and layout_height to match_parent?

Try this code

```
/******** Experimental Code **********/
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
LayoutParams parems = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATH_PARENT);
rl.setParameters(parems);
linLayout.addView(rl);
```

**UPDATE :**

Please show your activity_main.xml code and notice your api level. If so, I'm going to run your code.

Otherwise, have you try to set layout size from onMeasure()?

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = 0;
    switch (heightMode) {
    case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST: // wrap_confent
        heightSize = 400;
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY: // match_parent
        heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        break;
    }

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = 0;
    switch (widthMode) {

    case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST: // wrap_confent
        widthSize = 400;
        break;
    case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY: // match_parent
        widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        break;
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here.

First is that you need set the layout params for your RelativeLayout called "rl" when you add it to your LinearLayout called "linLayout." Do this with the following code:

```
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    linLayout.addView(rl, params);
```

Your other issue is that when you add your customViews to rl it is better to add a rule to the layout params than to use gravity.  The code below demonstrates this:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    CustomDrawableView arc = new CustomDrawableView(this,0,30);
    CustomDrawableView arcTwo = new CustomDrawableView(this, 50, 30);
    rl.addView(arc, lp);
    rl.addView(arcTwo, lp);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it also, and it still doesn't work. I'm trying to understand why. Is there something I should be overriding if i'm using a customview.